# Change UIBarButtonItem position

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to increase the navigation bar in my project with:

```
navigationBar?.frame.origin.y = +50
```

But it also change the left bar button item.
Is there any way to move it back to the original position?

[image: Image of the original navigation bar]

And then:

[image: Image of the navigation bar after the increasing]

Comment: why would you do that?! you can hide the navigation bar and add your custom view

Comment: follow this link its may be helpfull for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566216/vertically-aligning-uinavigationitems/17434530#17434530

Comment: @AhmadF It has a limitation though. If you add a loader on uiview, it will block the complete view. With standard navigation bar adding loader on UIView doesnt block the nav bar taps. If you want to do something like this, make a container of nav bar and add controllers as child

Comment: I will create custom navigation bar after hiding the default navigation bar. Looks like it is the best option. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to totally customized `navigation bar` then you should hide `default navigation bar` and you can use `UIView` work as `NavigationBar`. You can set desired height to it and you should keep it's width equal to your `screen width`. You should then add `UIButton` on that view at your desired position working as back button or other function!

Comment: It has a limitation though. If you add a loader on uiview, it will block the complete view. With standard navigation bar adding loader on UIView doesnt block the nav bar taps. If you want to do something like this, make a container of nav bar and add controllers as child

Comment: I will create custom navigation bar after hiding the default navigation bar. Looks like it is the best option. Thanks for your help!