# Override layoutSubviews to call [super layoutSubviews] and then find and reposition the button's view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to reposition my `UIBarButtonItem` so that it sits with it's edges against the top and right of the UINavigationBar. I found [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761183/change-position-of-uibarbuttonitem-in-uinavigationbar) on how to do this, but I don't really understand how to code it.

I've started by creating a new class called `CustomNavBar` which inherits from `UINavigationBar`. I then placed this method in the implementation:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{


}
```

What I don't understand is the part in the answer that says

```
call [super layoutSubviews] and then find and reposition the button's view.
```

How do I code this? Even a nudge in the right direction would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Find the button you want to move *after* you call `layoutSubviews` because it will be repositioned to where iOS wants it to be every time `layoutSubviews` is called.

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {   // Go through all subviews
        if (view == buttonYouWant) {  // Find the button you want
            view.frame = CGRectOffset(view.frame, 0, -5);   // Move it
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through the subviews and compare if the current one is the one you want by using `NSClassFromString`, like this for example:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"TheClassNameYouWant")]) {
            // Do whatever you want with view here
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use `NSLog` in the for loop to see the different subviews.

Comment: Why would you ever want to use `NSClassFromString` instead of `[TheClassNameYouWant class]`? In the latter case, you would get warnings after a refactor, which you wouldn't in the first case.

Comment: I assume `[TheClassNameYouWant class]` should be more performant as well