# UIBarButtonItem: Image offsets

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiedgeinsets

I am trying to create custom back bar button item using image. I've done it this way:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Back")
self.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = image
self.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "Back")
self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

But here's result:[image]

As you can see, it should be moved a little down and a little right. I tried to add offset to image this way:

```
self.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = image?.imageWithAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 40, 0, 0))
```

But it does not work, the same. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Although, I feel, there is a scope to move title bit up to match with back button, you can move nav bar button down by:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(5.0, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

To move it to right, try adding a flexible space, something like:

```
let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Comment: To move it down, I've put it in viewWillAppear method, but it does not work

Comment: Can you try moving your bar button using `navBar.leftBarButtonItem?.backgroundVerticalPositionAdjustmentForBarMetrics(UIBarMetrics.Default)`.

Comment: Adding a custom button may instead give you more control on positioning. Take a look at this ObjC [SO Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897470/ios7-excessive-navigationbar-button-padding) to get an idea.