# Add transparent space around a UIImage

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage

Lets say we have an image of 600X400 pixel and we want to end up with an new image of 1000x1000 pixel which contains the initial image in the centre and transparent space around it. How can I achieve that in code?

[image]

Comment: Should not have been closed IMO. Question is well defined and is useful.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You create a new image context that is 1000x1000, draw your old image in the middle, then get the new `UIImage` from the context.

```
// Setup a new context with the correct size
CGFloat width = 1000;
CGFloat height = 1000;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width, height), NO, 0.0);        
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();       
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);                             

// Now we can draw anything we want into this new context.
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake((width - oldImage.size.width) / 2.0f,
                            (height - oldImage.size.height) / 2.0f);
[oldImage drawAtPoint:origin];

// Clean up and get the new image.
UIGraphicsPopContext();                             
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Dear DrummerB! Thanks very much for posting a working solution. Only correctio was replace CGPoint origin = CGRectMake((width - oldImage.size.width) / 2.0f,
                            (height - oldImage.size.height) / 2.0f); with CGPoint origin = CGPointMake((width - oldImage.size.width) / 2.0f,
                            (height - oldImage.size.height) / 2.0f);

Comment: @DrummerB don't you want the `opaque` argument in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` to be NO since he wants transparent space?

Answer (score 56):

In Swift you can write an extension to UIImage that draws image with insets around it.

**Swift 3**:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
    func imageWithInsets(insets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
            CGSize(width: self.size.width + insets.left + insets.right,
                   height: self.size.height + insets.top + insets.bottom), false, self.scale)
        let _ = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let origin = CGPoint(x: insets.left, y: insets.top)
        self.draw(at: origin)
        let imageWithInsets = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return imageWithInsets
    }
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
    func imageWithInsets(insets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
            CGSizeMake(self.size.width + insets.left + insets.right,
                self.size.height + insets.top + insets.bottom), false, self.scale)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let origin = CGPoint(x: insets.left, y: insets.top)
        self.drawAtPoint(origin)
        let imageWithInsets = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return imageWithInsets
    }
}
```

Comment: any idea why sometimes this might return nil?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1623924-uigraphicsgetimagefromcurrentima: You should call this function only when a bitmap-based graphics context is the current graphics context. If the current context is nil or was not created by a call to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_:), this function returns nil.

Comment: @mixel Just a minor suggestion: it should be `return imageWithInsets?.withRenderingMode(renderingMode)` in order to support template images as well

Answer (score 28):

This is the solution in **Swift 4** inspired by DrummerB answer:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {

    func addImagePadding(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let width: CGFloat = size.width + x
        let height: CGFloat = size.height + y
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: width, height: height), false, 0)
        let origin: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: (width - size.width) / 2, y: (height - size.height) / 2)
        draw(at: origin)
        let imageWithPadding = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return imageWithPadding
    }
}
```

How to apply:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "your-image")!
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image.addImagePadding(x: 50, y: 50))
imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Features:

- Simply pass padding values via parameters
- Colored padding (by setting the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions opaque parameter to false)

Answer (score 2):

A fix for appsunited's answer with better naming convension. To not confuse it the function is mutating or not:

```
extension UIImage {
    func withPadding(_ padding: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        return withPadding(x: padding, y: padding)
    }

    func withPadding(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let newWidth = size.width + 2 * x
        let newHeight = size.height + 2 * y
        let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0)
        let origin = CGPoint(x: (newWidth - size.width) / 2, y: (newHeight - size.height) / 2)
        draw(at: origin)
        let imageWithPadding = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return imageWithPadding
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a category on UIImage and try this:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithInsets:(CGRect)insetRect image:(UIImage *)image {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, insetRect.origin.x+insetRect.size.width+image.size.width, insetRect.origin.y+insetRect.size.height+image.size.height);
    // Setup a new context with the correct size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newRect.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

    // Now we can draw anything we want into this new context.
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(insetRect.origin.x, insetRect.origin.y);
    [image drawAtPoint:origin];

    // Clean up and get the new image.
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```