# Move MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem to the right on Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, uinavigationitem, rightbarbuttonitem

is there a way to move MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem when it is attached to the navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem? 
Right now it looks like this:

[image: my image]

and I want it to look more like in the maps by Apple (**edit:** be closer to the edge):

[image]

Is there a way to do this? I've tried ImageInsets with no luck.

**Edit:** Here is the code in viewDidLoad

```
MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *trackingButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView.mapView];
trackingButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake( 0, -10, 0, 0 );

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = trackingButton;
```

Comment: Sorry, edited original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, I found a working solution based on accepted answer to this question: [How to Edit Empty Spaces of Left, Right UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationBar [iOS 7]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18918378/1333847)

So in my code it looks like this

```
UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                                         target:nil action:nil];
negativeSpacer.width = -7.5;

MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *trackingButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView.mapView];

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:negativeSpacer, trackingButton, nil] animated:NO];
```

Although it doesn't work as expected for iPhone 6 Plus, it's best solution for now. Thanks everyone for their help.

Answer (score 1):

```
button1.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4, 0, 0, 0);
```

The answer here: [Can I change the position of navigationbar item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761183/change-position-of-uibarbuttonitem-in-uinavigationbar)

**Beware, you change insets of the button that to be assigned to the rightBarButtonItem, not the rightBarButtonItem itself.**

Comment: There is no property imageEdgeInsets just imageInsets and I've already tried several things but the item didn't move..

Comment: Edited original post.

Comment: Try with this: [trackingButton setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:-10 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Comment: Tried and nothing changed, this particular button didn't move a bit.