# Two buttons in UINavigationBar not aligned

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have the following code in `viewDidLoad` to add two buttons on the right of a `UINavigationBar` - I omitted the code of the left "Cancel" button.

```
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                                    target: self
                                                                                    action: @selector(done:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                                    target: self
                                                                                    action: @selector(add:)];

    NSArray* buttons = @[addButton, doneButtonItem];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons;
```

Works great, but it doesn't look good, the "+" symbol seems bigger than the word "Done" and they appear off center of each other:

[image]

Is there a way to make this look nicer?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the default SystemItem, and I believe it's exactly how they should look like. Apple definitely had tuned the layout, so it's actually unnecessary to modify the position.

My suggestion is **just keep it, don't do anything**.

However, if you really want to change the default position, here are many solutions: [Change position of UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761183/change-position-of-uibarbuttonitem-in-uinavigationbar)

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the fact that I'm using a different font (Avenir) for the title. Maybe the dimensions of the plus sign are optimized for the standard system font. I will to look into that later today.