# iOS back button has no padding

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

When I push a viewcontroller on my navigation stack, the back button appears to be against the left side of the screen. How can I get the regular padding of the back button?

[image: No padding]

Here is how I present the view controller:

```
- (void)goToCollection:(UIButton *)btn {
    Card *colCard = (Card *)btn.userData;
    WViewController *vc = [WViewController new];
    NSString *colID = [[colCard.href componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject];
    vc.collectionID = colID;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Here's my view setup in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` :

```
//Profile View
ProfileViewController *pv = [ProfileViewController new];
UINavigationController *profNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pv];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window setRootViewController:profNav];
[self.window setTintColor:[UIColor Primary]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Is the image you posted an example of your app or what you expect to see?  This Back button with chevron seems consistent with other apps to me.  Otherwise, can you post your code so we can see how you are presenting the new view controller?

Comment: it's quite hard to see but the chevron is touching the left boundary of the screen

Comment: I also get 'Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for' when navigating

Comment: Have you ever checked with the view debugger?https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html

Comment: The UINavigationController in question is the root controller of the app delegate's 'window' - when I embed this controller in a UITabBarController there is no longer an issue

Answer (score 4):

As per apple documentation, you can not edit or modify back button in any case. Only allowed operation for back button is `show` and `hide` . 
So if you want something to do with back button, you need to hide it and create a customise left bar button item as back button.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES; //hides back button
    UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)]; // creates a new button
    [myButton setImage:[UIImage backButtonImage]; // sets image for new button
    [myButton setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -15, 0, 0)];//content edgeInset to provide required padding
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backToHOmePage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];//adding target for new button
    UIBarButtonItem *customBackBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton]; //custom bar button item
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBackBtn; //assigning to left bar button item

-(void)backToHOmePage
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
} // method to be triggered on tapping above button
```

Comment: +1 for `setContentEdgeInsets`.  I struggled to add padding around a UIButton's text.  First, I tried `myButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5,5,5,5)` with positive values--but that shrunk the padding.  Negative values did not increase the padding. To increase the padding around the text in Swift 2: `myButon.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5,5,5,5)`

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your AppDelegate

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:-3 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: I don't really want to hack this - I think there is an issue with my Navigation Stack

Comment: is the frame of your UINavigationController the same width as the UIViewController? Show us the code for when you created the navigation controller.

Comment: Instead of self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; and [self.window setRootViewController:profNav]; why don't you try  self.window.rootViewController = profNav;

Comment: I am not using storyboards / nib so I need to create the UIWindow myself

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761183/change-position-of-uibarbuttonitem-in-uinavigationbar