# Adding constraints to a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: xcode, swift, autolayout, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Xcode is not allowing me to put constraints on my `BarButtonItem` on a ViewController in the MainStoryBoard. It's appearing too far to the left where it's unreadable as shown in the image.

The image below shows where the `BarButtonItem` is. It's supposed to say "Item". I also looked on the preview split screen on Xcode and it looked fine for the iPhone6 but not for the iPhone 4 (it's half cut on the iPhone 4 but here its 3/4s cut). Here I'm running for the iPhone 6 and i get that.

How do I add constraints in Xcode or how do I add the constraints programmatically to this BarButtonItem?

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what constraint do you want to add? top constraint or?

Comment: I want to position the BarButtonItem more to the right. @OrkhanAlizade

Comment: are u add nav bar like element in storyboard? if yes - just add constraint not to the elements inside but to the navBar

Comment: How are you adding the UIBarButtonItem to your nav bar? With interface builder or code? If it's code could you post it?

Comment: @Kirill I tried that. It still is too far to the left. I'm adding the UIBarButtonItem with the interface builder.

Comment: need more information for resolving ur issue - can u share u project

Comment: @rinyfo4 if you are using IB then it should lock it into place. IB only allows a `UIBarButtonItem` in a specific place. Are you changing the frame or bounds or anything like that? Are you definitely adding a `UIBarButtonItem` and not a `UIButton`?

Comment: @ChrisByatt yes, it's definitely a `UIBarButtonItem` on a `Navigation Bar` in a viewController, (not a `Navigation Controller). Should I get rid of it as an IBOutlet?

Comment: I can share the project, but it's a MainStoryBoard issue. I just remade a new project to see if i was crazy, and the same thing happened. This time, the BarButtonItem appeared, but it was still too far to the left. You can recreate it by just adding the BarButtonItem to a nav-bar in a ViewController in the MainStoryBoard. I'll share the project if not. Let me know. Thanks @Kirill

Comment: @rinyfo4 this is my result in IB when I add a bar button item to a nav bar https://gyazo.com/ba9d0b3e4fc0e1f06b404d338aff61b4

Comment: It looks the same for me. Until i run it. When i run it it looks like it does above. @ChrisByatt

Comment: @rinyfo4 on which device? https://gyazo.com/acd3edec290b154fffff6058461d8561

Comment: iPhone 6. In your image #2, how would you make "Item" lower? That's my issue. I can't move it, right left up or down... @ChrisByatt

Comment: @rinyfo4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761183/change-position-of-uibarbuttonitem-in-uinavigationbar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92713/discussion-between-rinyfo4-and-chris-byatt).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drag and drop navigation bar in your xib / story board

[image]

U can add constraints to this navigation bar as per your requirement.

Then add Bar Button Item to your navigation bar

[image]

Bar Button Item takes it default position u cannot incorporate autolayout there.

Although if u want positions of Bar Button Item Fixed or Flexible u can make use of Fixed Space Bar Button Item or Flexible Space Bar Button Item.

[image]

If positions are fixed drag Fixed Space Bar Button between your two Bar Button Item's.
And if positions is not fixed its flexible drag Flexible Space Bar Button Item between your two Bar Button Item's.

Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: your_item_here, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: your_item_here, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 0, constant: 1)
your_item_here.addConstraint(rightConstraint)
```

**P.S** if you want to add constraint to your UIBarButtonItem, it will rise an error

```
Value of type 'UIBarButtonItem' has no member 'addConstraint'
```

**P.S.S**

Because of it is not a view class, you can't apply constraints to it.

Comment: I typed this into the ViewDidLoad. Not sure where else to put it... `let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: doneButton, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: doneButton.superview, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0.5)` I get the error: `Type of expression ambiguous without more context'

Comment: @rinyfo4 did you add your button as outlet?

Comment: I've updated my answer, but it won't work for UIBarItem

Comment: How did you add your item to navbar? Programmatically or via drag&drop?

Comment: I used drag and drop.

Comment: you putted it wrongly, I seem. Delete it and try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92712/discussion-between-rinyfo4-and-orkhan-alizade).

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade `UIBarButtonItem` is not a view class. You can't apply constraints to bar button items.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe just read carefully before your `-`! I said about it in my comments. I just shared code for the other cases.