# Customise UI Navigation Bar and button

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, ios7, uikit

Hello I am new to ios development and want to know how to customise  navigation bar buttons

This is what i used to change navigation bar color

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor]]
```

I want to change button colour

Here is a exmaple
[image]

Comment: button color or bar color?

Comment: button color and to make the button like the pic

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set navigation bar, assuming your first screen is SpalshViewController you need to set splash screen as a root view controller for navigation bar and then set navigation bar as root view controller like :

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
SplashScreenVC *obj =[CustomUtility getViewController:@"SplashScreenVC"];
self.navigationController =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:obj];
self.window.rootViewController =self.navigationController;
```

in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Now coming to customize navigation bar setting and appearance you need to set :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bg2.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Regular" size:18]}];
```

Now setting the custom bar buttons for navigation bar you need to create barbutton items like :

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftbtn;
UIBarButtonItem *rightbtn;

[self.navigationController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftbtn];
[self.navigationController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rightbtn];
```

customize`barbuttonItems` According to your need

if you want to set more than one buttons to the navigation bar you can add like:

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftbtn1;
UIBarButtonItem *leftbtn2;
UIBarButtonItem *rightbtn1;
UIBarButtonItem *rightbtn2;
[self.navigationController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:@[leftbtn1,leftbtn2]];
[self.navigationController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:@[rightbtn1,rightbtn2]];
```

Hope it will helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Create a **1x1 pixel** image with the color you want. Then add following code to your **AppDelegate** class.

```
UIImage *btnBgColor = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backColor"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage: btnBgColor 
                                        forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

OR

Write the below code on your base viewController class, then make this class as superclass of all your other view controllers.

```
UIButton* yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
yourButton.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

UIBarButtonItem* buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: yourButton];
self.navigationBar.leftBArButtonItems = @[buttonItem];
```

Comment: How can i use ui colour ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below navigation bar to customize. In Storyboard you have option to change the colour.

[image]

[image]

Otherwise you can put UIView to customize. Like below,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom button in navigation bar like:

```
    UIButton *btnObj = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnObj setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 44)];
    [btnObj setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
    [btnObj setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"<button background image>"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnObj addTarget:self action:@selector(btnObjClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *itemBtnObj = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnObj];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:itemBtnObj, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from story board itself.
Drag UINavigation Bar

[image]

Customise your navigation using images or background colors giving them shadows.

[image]

Add navigation item

[image]

you can customize those too using images or colors and images and position as per requirements.

[image]

To add constraints to the same refer my ans. [Adding constraints to a UIBarButtonItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211265/adding-constraints-to-a-uibarbuttonitem/33213764#33213764)

Hope it helps.. Happy Coding.. :)