# Change position of navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have a custom back button created as `UIBarButtonItem` and inserted to `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`. I need to move it a little bit to the left. I was able to move with an image of `UIBarButtonItem`, but hit area of the button remained on original place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change position of UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761183/change-position-of-uibarbuttonitem-in-uinavigationbar)

Comment: I have answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53028887/2395636). You can try!

Comment: I was trying it, but I had still problem with hit (touch) zones.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a custom UIButton with the frame you want and after that create the UIBarButtonItem(customView: UIButton) like this for example

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 45, height: 40))
let yourBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

Comment: This is how is the button created. Now I need to set X for some negative value to move it to the left, but it's not working.

Comment: Try use this button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0); but remember that this function can change the image position of your button but not the area where it can be clicked